# Yeoman JHipster (Angular +Spring+ Maven+MySQL) stack error

Tags: maven, yeoman, jhipster

I've created a **JHipster** application using angular+ spring+maven+mysql stack. The code is generated when trying to build, getting innumerous errors.
    First executed using mvn command line - mvn spring-boot:run
    as mentioned in the `https://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_app.html`. It didnt work, so imported the maven project in eclipse and tried to build. It is giving errors running into hundreds. I am sure that there might some configuration which is being missed. Kindly advise.

```
Errors with running maven at command prompt:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22:41 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-06T11:46:14+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/136M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project om: Could not resolve dependencies for
 project om:om:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact net.sf.saxon:Saxo
n-HE:jar:9.6.0-4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET req
uest of: net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.6.0-4/Saxon-HE-9.6.0-4.jar from central failed:
 SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException

Errors when building with eclipse:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'. strict.dtd  /test/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-svgo/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/sax/examples  line 81 DTD Problem
The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'. strict.dtd  /test/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/sax/examples line 81 DTD Problem
The declaration for the entity "ContentType" must end with '>'. strict.dtd  /test/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/examples line 81 DTD Problem
Start tag (<form>) not closed properly, expected '>'.   _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 12 HTML Problem
Start tag (<form>) not closed properly, expected '>'.   _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 12 HTML Problem
Start tag (<input>) not closed properly, expected '>'.  _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 40 HTML Problem
Start tag (<input>) not closed properly, expected '>'.  _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 40 HTML Problem
Start tag (<tbody>) not closed properly, expected '>'.  _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 153    HTML Problem
Start tag (<tbody>) not closed properly, expected '>'.  _entities.html  /test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/entity/templates/src/main/webapp/app  line 153    HTML Problem
Attribute (cellpadding) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents. pkginfo.html    /test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-proxy/node_modules/pkginfo/docs  line 1  HTML Problem
Attribute (cellpadding) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents. pkginfo.html    /test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/http-
```

Comment: You still need to read about Jhipster. I suggest you to use IntilliJ(Community edition free).

Answer (score 1):

You can see an explanation of your problem in your log:

```
    Could not transfer artifact net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.6.0-4 
from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
GET request of: net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.6.0-4/Saxon-HE-9.6.0-4.jar 
from central failed: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

It says that you have a problem in the connection to the maven repository, this problem could be due a network issue, or also some maven miss configurations.